# PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx vs PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine

Tags: windows, kernel

PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx is returning successfully, however whenever a new process is created, the callback function CreateProcessNotifyEX isn't being called. On the otherhand if I were to use PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine instead, the callback function CreateProcessNotify would be called. Why is it that when I replace PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine with PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx and CreateProcessNotify with CreateProcessNotifyEx does the OS seem to not notify my kernel driver when a new Process is about to be created?

This Code right now is based off of memory as I'm home right now.

```
**Class.cpp:**    
Class::Class{   
//Other Person's Code    
PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(CreateProcessNotifyEX, FALSE);    
//More of Other People's Code    
}


void Class::(PEPROCESS Process, HANDLE ProcessID, PPS_CREATE_INFO CreateInfo){
//Code that never occurs (breakpoint doesn't arrive)
}

**Class.h**    
(Library is included because code originally used PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine)    

void CreateProcessNotifyEx(PEPROCESS Process, HANDLE ProcessID, PPS_CREATE_INFO CreateInfo);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recall more than that. It's something that bugging me.

Comment: So I found out the problem, PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx returns Status_Access_Denied. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559953.aspx) states that the module containing the callback must have the `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY` flag set in the PE header. Not having that flag will cause the API to return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.

[IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339.aspx):

> Code integrity checks are forced. If you set this flag and a section
>   contains only uninitialized data, set the PointerToRawData member of
>   IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER for that section to zero; otherwise, the image
>   will fail to load because the digital signature cannot be verified.

Use the linker's [`/INTEGRITYCHECK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195769.aspx) switch to enable.